# send notification email if process is not running

Tags: shell

I am using the following shellscript to check running process in a cron job:

```
ps -ef|grep myprocess|grep -v "grep"
```

I then need to send an email if the result is empty(meaning process is not running), how do I script this?

Comment: You can avoid the ``grep -v "grep"`` dance like this: ``ps -ef|grep '[m]yprocess'``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution:

```
pgrep processname &>/dev/null && exit 0
echo |mail -s"Aiie, process processname not running!" mail@addresse.here
```

Then put it in a crontab like already suggested. Of course, it means you must have the `mail` command installed.

Comment: Whats the pipe in front of `mail` for?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
PROCESS_FOUND=`ps -ef|grep myprocess|grep -v grep`
if [ "$PROCESS_FOUND" = "" ]
then
    #send mail from here ...Process not running
fi
```

Comment: Depends on the output format of `ps` and what not. Better to check the exit code from grep: `ps -ef | grep '[m]yprocess' >/dev/null || echo Subject: myprocess died | sendmail you`